# Copying & Modifying specific values from each Form submit when copying to another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I got a situation where 2 independent parties need access to the same data, but their back-end that uses the data needs a different format, e.g. one party needs to see "Soccer", the other needs to see "1". 
This input comes from various users through a Google Form.

I previously ran a time interval script that would copy over all data from sheet 1, then copy it to sheet 2, then a double loop would kick (using var i) in to search all columns and replace specific strings on sheet 2 with a numeric value.
This script worked, but due to it's inefficiency it started to crash once I started to have more data.

So I am trying to reduce the dataset by just handling the data that comes from each individual Form Submit.
I tried 2 different approaches: 
1) Grab values to copy, modify values, then copy to new sheet
2) Grab values to copy, copy to new sheet, then modify these new values (lastrow)

I know the copy bit works in both scripts I wrote but my modification does not, when using the debugger it shows me the modified data is same as the original and this is in fact what happens the copy is identical.
I realize I am probably making a very basic mistake, but I am blind as to what it is. Searching for similar threads on Stackoverflow and other sites I did not come to a resolution.

Current code:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){


  var responses = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var projects =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var row = responses.getLastRow();
  var col = responses.getLastColumn();
  var copy = responses.getRange(row, 1, 1, col)
  var modify = copy.getValues();
  for (var i=0; i < modify.length; i++){
    if (modify [i] == "SearchString1"){
        modify [i] = "1";
      }
      else if (modify [i] == "SearchString2"){
        modify [i] = "0";
      }
      else if (modify [i] == "SearchString3"){
        modify [i] = "1";
      }
  projects.appendRow(modify);
    }
}
```

This code will copy the data, but not modify it.
I had a variation where i used .setvalues but that resulted in the same end result.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was all about location identifiers. 
The getvalues created a double array and the append was in the loop instead of outside of it. I had to specify the append and modification better.

Fixed code:

```
  for (var i=0; i < modify[0].length; i++){
    if (modify[0][i] == "SearchString1"){
        modify[0][i] = "1";
      }
      else if (modify[0][i] == "SearchString2"){
        modify[0][i] = "0";
      }
      else if (modify[0][i] == "SearchString3"){
        modify[0][i] = "1";
      }
    }
  projects.appendRow(modify[0]);
}
```